# Cooking.SE version of Photo.SE's blog incentive

Tags: discussion, blog

As long as the unicorn bucks are flying out the door, from [a discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4070278#4070278) in [#TheFryingPan](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16/the-frying-pan), a suggestion on how to drive blog posts and interesting questions:

StackExchange could purchase and send interesting ingredients and/or equipment to people who agree to ask questions and write blog entries about them.

The Photo.SE version: [Call for participants in Photography Gear Lending Library](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2011/call-for-participants-in-photography-gear-lending-library)

Comment: Don't we..ya know...need a blog first?

Comment: Yes. You do (need a blog first).